# Saving Skin weights Issue

Tags: animation, maya, rigging

I have Skinned the character using rig simulator and now wanted to add Bendy controls.. How can I export the skin weights and apply on modified rig?

Answer (score 0):

In Maya this requires using the scripting language or the API and takes a lot of work to do properly.

Download the comet scripts, they have this functionality and it is very handy.

http://comet-cartoons.com/melscript.php